# swipe action not popping to previous controller - what am I missing?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have the UI Gesture Recognizer connected to my swift file and have this code to pop over to the previous controller. However, I'm not having luck atm. what am I missing?

```
@IBAction func leftswipe(_ sender: Any) {
    [navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need embed first viewController into UINavigationController and use "Show" or "Show Detail" segue`s type.

Comment: So I am unable to use swipe gestures regarding navigation without the navigation controller?

Comment: Hello. If you not use UINavigationController. Then you use "Present Modally" segue`s type. And for go back you need use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; in leftswipe function

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `navigationController`, it must be nil. Are you sure you have the first viewController is embedded in navigation controller and this viewcontroller is in the navigation controller stack? Also I noticed `[]` brackets in your code. Don't use that in Swift.

Comment: Thanks for the [ ] note. Your comment raises another question, do I need a pre-existing nav controller in my project for the swipe gesture to work?

Comment: Yes. If you're trying to pop from the current viewcontroller, it means that you are trying to pop back to the previous view controller - means it's already in the navigation stack. So my guess is that you don't have a navigation controller either in your storyboard or in your code. Let me know if that answers your question.